# Weird behaviour due to data loss from sqlite database on iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, sqlite

I have a phonegap app which runs on both Android and iOS.

I am facing a weird problem. My app is password protected, and only after entering the correct password, the user is logged in. Also, the app has multiple screens.

Suppose I am on a particular screen (after logging in), and switch off the device (with the app still running), switch on the device back and launch my application. It starts back from the screen which was visible on Android but on iOS, nothing shows up, just a white screen.

After some debugging, i found out that log-in credentials were there in sqlite3 database on Android and not on iOS. Why is that ?

Comment: I might suggest you put in a breakpoint/NSLog message where (a) you save the credentials; and (b) where you load the credentials and confirm that they're being saved like you think they should be (before the user switches off the device) and that they're being retrieved like you think they should be (after the user switches it back on and restarts app). Personally, I wouldn't suspect iOS/SQLite issue.

Comment: i resolved the issue by creating the database, earlier i was copying the database file from assets to the target location... thank you for looking into it